# Pharo: How to convert ASCII character into ASCII decimal

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, mit-scratch

I'm making a Scratch 1.4 mod using Smalltalk (from MIT) and researching this got me absolutely nowhere.

Converting ASCII characters seems easy, but how do you do it in Smalltalk?

If you have no clue, the ASCII number of 65 **should** give you "A" (don't quote me on that.)

If this seems utterly stupid to ask, it took me 2 days worth of time to research and find out how to add a *function* in Smalltalk. That's how much I have been struggling on this, as I know very little about Smalltalk, but I plan to extend this knowledge.

Comment: In Pharo there is a _Finder_ tool where you can enter `$A . 65`, ask to find examples and it will show you all messages that return `65` when sent to `$A`. I was not able to find that in Squeak, but as the example finder is quite old I suspect they are just hiding it well

Comment: Smalltalk is a simple language, but a very large and complex system. The key to finding your way into it, is to understand which of the many tools and browsers might help you get to an answer. Experienced smalltalkers look at how things are implemented (implementors), or used (senders and references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't get a more specific answer for Scratch, here's what works in Pharo (which was forked from Squeak, which is what Scratch is based on):

To convert from a character to its ascii value, just as for its... you guessed it, `asciiValue`:

`$A asciiValue` (which evaluates to `65`)

To convert from an integer/ascii value to a character, just create a new character object with that value:

`Character value: 65` (which evaluates to `$A`)

I don't think this is Pharo-specific, so should work in Squeak (and therefore in Scratch) as well.

Comment: Thank you. 45 minutes of searching for this got nothing. I appreciate it!

Comment: You're most welcome. And it sounds like you may be searching the wrong way, or in the wrong places... A good starting point would've been the `Character` class in your image, where you would've seen both the methods I mention (`asciiValue` on the instance side, and `value` on the class side). If you're looking to get started with Smalltalk in general, [Pharo by example](http://pharobyexample.org/) should be very helpful.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, how could I make it backwards? For example, input 65 to get A?